# Using ActionServerWrapper to run actionserver writtten in cpp

Tags: ros, action, actionlib, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a actionserver written in C++. I want to run this actionserver using actionserverwrapper in smach. Is this possible? Or  we have to write the actionserver in python itself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190771/using-actionserverwrapper-to-run-actionserver-writtten-in-cpp/) by [Arun](https://answers.ros.org/users/19860/arun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to admit that I have never used actionserverwrapper but after reading [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) I understand that it is used to wrap an entire statemachine into an actionserver. I don't think that is what you want to do.

Regarding your problem: It does not matter in which language the action server is implemented. You can just crate an [action client](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Client%20(Python)) in your python smach and call the C++ action server.

If this is not the answer you were hoping for, maybe additional information and code samples would clarify what the actual problem is.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1